# For which values of $p$ the improper integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^p~\ln(x)} $ converges?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm having trouble in the following problem

> Find the values of $p$ for which the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^p~\ln(x)} $ converges.

So far I separated the integral into two separate integrals,  $\int_0^\frac{1}{2} \frac{dx}{x^p~\ln(x)} $ and  $\int_\frac{1}{2}^1 \frac{dx}{x^p~\ln(x)} $, for the first one I found that it converges for values of $p$ where $p\le0$, however I don't seem to find the way of proving the convergence of the second integral, tried using the power series for $\ln(x)$ but I'm not sure how to proceed, any insight would be appreciate it,
Thanks.

Comment: The $1/x^p$ does not change the convergence of the integral (it is bounded from above and below). So, you should ask yourself, does $$\int_\frac{1}{2}^1 \frac{dx}{\ln(x)}$$ converge?

Comment: When you say that it is bounded from aboce and below, you mean that $\int_\frac{1}{2}^1 \frac{dx}{x^p~\ln(x)} $ is dominated by $\int_\frac{1}{2}^1 \frac{dx}{\ln(x)} $ for all $p$? But if $0$ is greater than $p$ wouldn't $ \frac{1}{x^p~\ln(x)} $ be greater than $\frac{1}{\ln(x)} $?
Thanks.

Comment: I mean for $x\in [1/2;1]$ we have for $p>0$  $$ 1\leq \frac{1}{x^p} \leq 2^p.$$ Then I can squeeze the integral with the factor $1/x^p$ between the one without (with the constants above).